# Hacking an Automated Air Gap backup with USB drives

Tags: usb-storage

I am wanting to create an automated air gapped backup onto a couple of USB hard drives.   (FWIW, the server these will connect to a Linux server).   I'm fairly certain I can build a circuit which will periodically automatically switch a couple relays, and I am confident I can trigger a backup when a device is seen as being plugged into the server.    I am aware of the concern of "safely removing hard drives", and this can be ignored (I'll do the backup and then unmount the drive.  Also I'll use a journalling filesystem)

The part which I am uncertain about is how to connect the relays to the external drives.  I would be grateful for any experience/advice/knowledge around this, particularly the following -

1. If I get 3.5" hard drives, and leave them physically connected to the computer, and turn the power to the drives on and off, will this look to the computer like drives being plugged in/unplugged?
2. Another strategy I've thought of which will allow me to use 2.5" drives would be to intercept the voltage line on the USB cable.  Is bastardizing USB cables (and changing the length of the ground and voltage lines) likely to interfere with file transfer speeds or reliability?  If so, is this significantly more of an issue for newer USB standards?
3. (Bonus if you can comment on this - if not, please answer anyway, as I know this might be outside of scope here) - is anyone perchance able to confirm if the typical blue relays found on IOT boards designed to control 110/240 volt C, 10 amp loads - eg SRD-05VDC-5L-C - are able to switch 5 volt DC loads?   (I am guessing that they have a coil so they are creating a physical contact rather then an optocoupler so this should work?)

Comment: If you leave USB HDDs connected they are no longer considered air gapped.  They sell USB hubs with ON/OFF buttons, that would physically disconnect the drives, provided your willingness to stay around for the backup to happen and finish

Comment: @Ramhound, the whole idea is to create a  device which, conceptually, is connected for a limited time and is then automatically physically disconnected (outside control of a networked computer) - I'm wrestling with the way to automate the disconnection. If you dont consider this airgapped then our definition of airgapped is different, but it doesnt really change my goal.

Comment: @ramhound Thank you for your comment. On reflection getting a 4 port usb3 hub with switches could be helpful - as I can possibly hack the switch instead - and reducing risks associated with hacking a cable - and will allow me to use 2.5" disks which are cheaper, while also using a single usb connection to the PC.